# Transform bad formatted string to Scala class

Tags: string, scala

We would like to format the following string:

`(1854288750,binance,live),(1854288751,bitrix,live)`

to the folllowing case class in Scala:

`case class Account(login :String, platform: String, type: String)`

Which is the most efficient way since we do not want to use `replaceAll`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make an *instance* of that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pattern matching

```
case class Account(login :String, platform: String, aType: String)

object Application extends App {

  //parse single string
  def parse(input: String): Option[Account] = {
    if (!input.startsWith("(") || !input.endsWith(")"))
      return None

    //split input to list using separator
    input.substring(1, input.length).split(",").toList match {
      //if format is correct return instance of your data class
      case List(login, platform, aType) => Some(Account(login, platform, aType))
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  //parse list of strings
  def parse(input: List[String]): List[Account] =
    input.map(parse).flatMap(_.toList)

  println(parse("(1854288750,binance,live)"))
  println(parse("(1854288751,bitrix,live)"))

  val input: List[String] = List("(1854288750,binance,live)", "(1854288751,bitrix,live)", "abc",
    "(1854288750,binance,live", "1854288750,binance,live)")
  //two-elements list
  println(parse(input))
}
```